# How to show UIAlertView without dimming the background in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, background, uialertview

Dimming the background upon showing an UIAlertView seems the default behavior of iOS. Can I disable this effect so that the background will not be dimmed, because I have a rather dark background already. Thanks!

Comment: The very nature of an alert view is that it is modal; it should be the _only_ thing the user sees or needs to see. That is why Apple has introduced this dimming behavior. If you are concerned that the user needs to see your background while the alert view is present, then you are misusing UIAlertView and should consider some other interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIAlertView doesn’t provide a way to do that. If you need that behavior, you’ll have to find a third-party alert view that does or create your own custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with the built-in `UIAlertView` class from Apple. Try checking out [this](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) custom alert view class, although you will need to further customize it to remove the background on the pop-up. Other than that, you could make a custom class from scratch.